# Plural "-i" vs. "-uses"

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

Similarly to [Latin words with no plurals in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/493066/211388) I still have trouble with some plurals when the word ends in *-us*.

For example, I have often been told that the plural for *cactus* is *cacti*, but then some argue it is *cactuses*.

[Merriam Webster states](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octopus) that it could be either *octopuses* or *octopi*, but then someone a while back said it is actually *[octopodes](https://scrabble.wonderhowto.com/news/octopus-conundrum-octopuses-vs-octopi-vs-octopodes-0123668/)*. Huh?

When talking about the plural for hippopotamus, is it hippopotamus**es** or hippopotam**i**?

How do I tell when to use *-uses* rather than *-i*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plurals of foreign words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/plurals-of-foreign-words) Basically, if unsure, check in a good dictionary (see resources page on ELU.Meta). They give idiomatic usages. // There is a misquote in your question. The linked article says that 'octopodes _is not incorrect_, but is a very infrequently used variant' (to paraphrase).

Comment: _Octopus_ is derived from Greek, not Latin, so it doesn't follow the rules for Latin words. _Cacti_ is widely used by enthusiasts (at least, in the UK).

Comment: As discussed in the other questions and their answers, there are multiple options for the plurals of some words (e.g. octopus which many people don't know or can't agree about), and using the wrong plural of these words is very common even for native English speakers, so I wouldn't worry too much if there doesn't seem to be a clear answer.